# Access $(VCToolsInstallDir) from a non CPP project

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, wix, projects-and-solutions

I have a WiX project and need to call editbin.exe to change the stack size on an executable.

I am working in VS2017 and have the component "VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools" installed with puts editbin in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86".

I have also installed the component "Visual C++ tools for CMake" which when in "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" typing "echo %VCToolsInstallDir% returns "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023"

But when I use this in a .wixprof file such as:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="call &quot;$(VCToolsInstallDir)bin\Hostx86\$(configuration)\editbin.exe&quot; /stack:5242880 &quot;<path to exe>&quot;" />
</Target>
```

It tries to use the path "bin\Hostx86\x86\editbin.exe"

What am I missing? How can I get $(VCToolsInstallDir) into the project?

Answer (score 0):

Before using `$(VCToolsInstallDir)`, you need to import some targets files containing the definition of this macro. But I don't suggest you do that. These files depend on each other. It means that you need to make the C++ build tool be compatible with wix build tool. It will be a big work.

Comment: ok thanks, I need to access editbin.exe (either from .wixproj, or from the .csproj) what would be the best way to do this without hardcoding a path?

Comment: Maybe you can create a macro for this path in windows environment variables. `setx {name} "path"`

Comment: I can run VSDevCmd.bat in a cmd window and it loads VCToolsInstallDir as an environment variable.  I just want to do this inside MSBuild

Comment: Maybe the [customized targets file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#customize-the-solution-build) can meet your requirement.

Comment: For someone who had a good reason the target file that defines it is $(VCTargetsPath)/Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props